# Checking the "cleanliness" of an image for Optical Character Recognition

Tags: image-processing, optical-char-recognition

Is there some mechanism to say whether the image is "clean" for the purpose of image processing?

For example, in the following image, the topmost row is the cleanest and the bottom one is the least clean. As a result, the top-image gives accurate output; the bottom-one gives less accurate.

[Examples of noisy and noise-less images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMUm0m.png)

The purpose is to use the image for Optical Character Recognition.
And, I wanted to check beforehand, if the image is sufficiently clean or not.

Comment: Well, *cleanliness* in not an awfully technical term. I assume you mean "absence of noise". Posting some images with examples would be of great help.

Comment: Please do not refer to your profile pic for additional info. First of all, it is small and you can change it at will, thereby invalidating this question when you decide to use something fancy. All necessary info should be in the question.

Comment: I would start by reducing the colour depth to eliminate most of the noise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your images are gray-scaled. In order to perform the OCR you might want to first threshold it to apply OCR on the binary image.

The effectiveness of the thresholding will definitely affect the performance of the algorithm. A simple way is say [Otsu's thresholding](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html). In your case, you can think of this as character vs. non-character pixels. And the measure of the *cleanliness* can be treated as the amount of *energy* (such as class variance) of the non-character pixels.

Unfortunately the measure I described is *post* applying your (first step) of OCR. Hence, I am not sure if this helps you.

Comment: You seem to have understood my question, without me using proper words.

Comment: The downloadable code in the link provided seems to be corrupt (or this is what is reported by winzip, while untarring). Do other stack-exchangers have the same observation?

Comment: @eeerahul I don't quite know know about the code. i just referred that page for good explanations and visuals. If you want code - may be you should check if OpenCV or matlab has implementation.